# How to check element is visible on mouse hover or not

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium, protractor, end-to-end

1. I want to check if the Pencil button is appearing on mousehover or not.
2. Here is the HTML:

   ```
   <h2 class="col-md-12" data-ng-mouseover="editmode = true" data-ng-mouseleave="editmode = false">
       <span class="ng-binding" data-ng-bind-html="selectedPage.htmlTitle">New Page</span>
       <a class="btn btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-pencil ng-hide" data-ng-click="toggleEditMode()" data-ng-show="editmode"></a>
   </h2>
   ```
3. I am using the following code for testing if the pencil button is visible on mousehover or not, but it is not working:

   ```
   browser
       .actions()
       .mouseMove(element(by.css("a[data-ng-click='toggleEditMode()']")))
       .perform();
   expect(element(by.css("a[data-ng-click='toggleEditMode()']")).isDisplayed())
       .toBeTruthy();
   ```
4. I want verify first that the pencil button is visible or not, and after that I want to click on the pencil button.

Comment: Please elaborate "it is not working". Any errors?